# mustache.js date formatting

Tags: string, json, mustache, date-parsing

I have started using mustache.js and so far I am very impressed. Although two things puzzle me. The first leads on to the second so bear with me.

**My JSON**

```
{"goalsCollection": [
    {
        "Id": "d5dce10e-513c-449d-8e34-8fe771fa464a",
        "Description": "Multum",
        "TargetAmount": 2935.9,
        "TargetDate": "/Date(1558998000000)/"
    },
    {
        "Id": "eac65501-21f5-f831-fb07-dcfead50d1d9",
        "Description": "quad nomen",
        "TargetAmount": 6976.12,
        "TargetDate": "/Date(1606953600000)/"
    }
]};
```

**My handling function**

```
function renderInvestmentGoals(collection) {
    var tpl = '{{#goalsCollection}}<tr><td>{{Description}}</td><td>{{TargetAmount}}</td><td>{{TargetDate}}</td></tr>{{/goalsCollection}}';
    $('#tblGoals tbody').html('').html(Mustache.to_html(tpl, collection));
}
```

**Q1**
As you can see my 'TargetDate' needs parsing but I am unsure of how to do that within my current function.

**Q2**
Say I wanted to perform some function or formatting on one or more of my objects before rendering, what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: there is a github issue on this topic: https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/41

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've been using Mustache for my projects as well, due to its ability to be shared across client/server. What I ended up doing was formatting all values (dates, currency) to strings server-side, so I don't have to rely on helper Javascript functions. This may not work well for you though, if you're doing logic against these values client-side.

You might also want to look into using [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), which is essentially Mustache, but with extensions that may help with client-side formatting (and more). The loss here is that you will probably not be able to find a server-side implementation of handlebars, if that matters to you.

Comment: This is a bad answer. The formatting of numbers is presentation logic - not business or application logic. It does not belong in the server. Rather, it should be part of the template language or gui somehow.

Comment: I agree with previous comment : the answer "use a lamdba" is the correct one

Comment: "It's presentation logic" is too shallow.  How would one reuse a complex formatting function in Mustache?  Copying+pasting lambdas to follow such a dogmatic view of things is worse than adding strings to server data.  Creating a string representation isn't a presentation function unless toString() is.  If how to format something is object-dependent, it sure belongs in that object.  Otherwise you get duplicated formatting code all over a project and differences arise.  Almost every company makes this costly mistake.  Get away from dogma and be pragmatic.

Answer (score 21):

You can use "Lambdas" from [mustache(5)](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

```
"TargetDate": "/Date(1606953600000)/",
"FormatDate": function() {
    return function(rawDate) {
        return rawDate.toString();
    }
}, ...
```

Then in the markup:

```
<td>
{{#FormatDate}}
    {{TargetDate}}
{{/FormatDate}}
</td>
```

From the link:

> When the value is a callable object, such as a function or lambda, the object will be invoked and passed the block of text. The text passed is the literal block, unrendered.

Comment: Ok, i get how this would work but how do I construct my JSON to include the 'FormatDate' function, as my result is a serialized dictionary?

Comment: You would have to use JSONP, ie. return an executable script instead of pure data... which kinda defeats data/presentation/logic separation.

Comment: You could also use something like : Mustache.to_html(tpl, $.extend({}, DefaultTplFunctions, collection}) and then the object DefautTplFunctions contains FormatDate fucntion (and other functions similar ot this one)

Comment: The link for `lambda` is broken

Answer (score 10):

I have created a small extension for Mustache.js which enables the use of formatters inside of expressions, like {{expression | formatter}}

You would anyway need to create a function that parses your date value like this:

```
      Mustache.Formatters = {
        date: function( str) {
          var dt = new Date( parseInt( str.substr(6, str.length-8), 10));
          return (dt.getDate() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getFullYear());
        }
      };
```

And then just add the formatter to your expressions:

```
{{TargetDate | date}}
```

You can grab the code from here: http://jvitela.github.io/mustache-wax/

Comment: Took me a bit to realize that mustache-wax.js does not work when pulling a #template from the html where it will be rendered, or is there another method of using it? I currently wrap things on a <template id="temp"></template>

Comment: Could you provide an example? Normally you load first the templates into a string and then pass it to Mustache.render.

Answer (score 7):

It's a long time ago but got on this looking for exactly the same. Mustachejs (now) allows you to call functions of the passed data and not only that; in the function the value of `this` is whatever value is true in a section.

If my template is like this:

```
{{#names}}
    <p>Name is:{{name}}</p>
    <!-- Comment will be removed by compileTemplates.sh
         #lastLogin is an if statement if lastLogin it'll do this 
         ^lastLogin will execute if there is not lastLogin      
    -->
    {{#lastLogin}}
    <!-- 
      formatLogin is a method to format last Login 
      the function has to be part of the data sent 
      to the template
    -->
    <p>Last Login:{{formatLogin}}</p>
    {{/lastLogin}}
    {{^lastLogin}}
    not logged in yet
    {{/lastLogin}}
    {{#name}}
     passing name to it now:{{formatLogin}}
    {{/name}}
{{/names}}
```

And Data like this:

```
var data={
    names:[
        {name:"Willy",lastLogin:new Date()}
    ],
    formatLogin:function(){
          //this is the lastDate used or name based on the block
                  //{{#name}}{{formatLogin}}{{/name}}:this is name
                  //{{#lastLogin}}{{formatLogin}}{{/lastLogin}}:this is lastLogin
          if(!/Date\]$/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(this))){
              return "Invalid Date:"+this;
          }
          return this.getFullYear()
            +"-"+this.getMonth()+1
            +"-"+this.getDate();
    }
};
var output = Mustache.render(templates.test, data);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timestamp using simple String methods:

```
goalsCollection.targetDate = goalsCollection.targetDate.substring(6,18);
```

Of course, this depends on your timestamp being the same length each time. Another option is:

```
goalsCollection.targetDate = 
  goalsCollection.targetDate.substring(6, goalsCollection.targetDate.length - 1);
```

These techniques aren't specific to Mustache and can be used to manipulate data for any library. See the [Mozilla Developer Center Documentation on substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To declare a function within a json you can always do this.

```
var json = '{"RESULTS": true, "count": 1, "targetdate" : "/Date(1606953600000)/"}'

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj.newFunc = function (x) {
  return x;
}

//OUTPUT
alert(obj.newFunc(123));
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example of a 'lambda' function for parsing an ISO-8601 date and formatting as UTC:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Start",
    "date": "2020-04-11T00:32:00.000-04:00"
  },
  {
    "name": "End",
    "date": "2022-04-11T00:32:00.000-04:00"
  },
]

var template = `
{{#items}}
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
  {{#dateFormat}}
     {{date}}
  {{/dateFormat}}
{{/items}}
`;


var html = Mustache.render(template, {
  items: data,
  dateFormat: function () {
    return function (timestamp, render) {
      return new Date(render(timestamp).trim()).toUTCString();
    };
  }
});

document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@4.2.0/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

If you want fancier date formatting you could use for example something like:

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'short',
    year : 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'
})
// outputs '14 Apr 2022, 11:11'
```